# using ServletContext and ServletConfig in scriptlets and EL

Tags: jstl, el, jsp-tags

I tried to run the following lines.

```
<%=application.getInitParameter("tagline")%>               
<br />
<%=config.getInitParameter("admincontact")%>

${initParam.tagline}
<br />
${pageContext.servletConfig.initParameter("admincontact")}
```

And my web.xml is

```
<servlet>
<jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
<init-param>
    <param-name>admincontact</param-name>
    <param-value>8939302763</param-value>  
</init-param>
</servlet>
    <context-param>
<param-name>tagline</param-name>
<param-value>Each one Plant one</param-value>
```

I get a exception at 
`${pageContext.servletConfig.initParameter("admincontact")}`
and null value for
`<%=config.getInitParameter("admincontact")%>`.

Regards,
John

Comment: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Unable to find method [initParameter] with [1] parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [FAQ on JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/InitParamsThruExpressionLanguage) about this.

It states the following;

> **How to access servlet init parameters using EL?**
>
> You **cannot** use the following syntax to access servlet init parameters:
>
> `${pageContext.servletConfig.initParameter.name}`
>
> You cannot get Servlet init parameters using this technique. The
>   getInitParameter(java.lang.String name) does not fit in this case,
>   because it requires some arguments.
>
> According to the JavaBean spec, the property has getter & setter
>   methods in the form
>
> `public type1 getXXX()` -- WITH NO ARGUMENTS.
>
> `public void setXXX(type1)`
>
> Now consider the pageContext as bean Object. The
>   PageContext class has methods like getServletConfig(), getRequest(),
>   getSession() etc. You can access these like pageContext.page,
>   pageContext.request etc in EL.
>
> ServletContext object has a couple of methods like getMajorVersion(),
>   getMinorVersion() with no args. so we can access these methods
>   treating it as properties to sevletContext bean as
>   pageContext.servletContext.majorVersion and
>   pageContext.servletContext.minorVersion.
>
> If you want to access Servlet init parameters using EL, then it is
>   better to create a Map of the init parameters for the servlet and
>   place it in the request as a scoped variable -- let's say
>   initParameters. You would then be able to obtain any param by name
>   with ${requestScope.initParameters.name}.
>
> **NOTE**:
>
> We can access context init parameters with `${initParam.name}`

Comment: "If you want to access Servlet init parameters using EL, then it is better to create a Map of the init parameters for the servlet and place it in the request as a scoped variable" How to do this?

Comment: @John: If your not fussed specifically about using EL, then I'd suggest just going with the scriptlet calls <%= pageContext.getServletConfig().getInitParameter("admincontact") %> and <%= application.getInitParameter("tagline") %> I think you have these back the front in your original question, which may lead to some of the issues you are facing. **Disclaimer** It's been a while since I've used JSP and Java also.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mr Moose's answer, I have found this solution that uses EL defining a custom tag.
It worked in my case.
Here the [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1398019?start=0&tstart=0)

Basically you have to create a Java class like this:

```
package example.customTags;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspPage;

public class MyFunctions {

        public static String getJspInitParameter(JspPage page, String param){
            return page.getServletConfig().getInitParameter(param);
        }
    }
```

Create a tld file like this (my filepath is `WEB-INF/myTags/customTags.tld`):

```
<taglib>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
    <short-name>Functions</short-name>
    <function>
        <name>getJspInitParameter</name>
        <function-class>example.customTags.MyFunctions</function-class>
        <function-signature>
            java.lang.String getJspInitParameter(javax.servlet.jsp.JspPage, java.lang.String)
        </function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

And use it in your JSP like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="my" uri="../WEB-INF/myTags/customTags.tld"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:out value="${my:getJspInitParameter(pageContext.page, 'admincontact')}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```